# About web_reg_find() in loadrunner

Tags: performance, testing, controller, loadrunner

I am trying to measure time for next button one page to another. To do this I start transaction before to press button, I press the next button , when the next page loaded I end the transaction. Between this transaction process I use web_reg_find() and check specific text to verify that page.

When I use controller that transaction measured 5 sec , then I modified transaction content and delete web_reg_find() after I measured that transaction it will be 3 sec. Is that normal ?

Because I do load test , functionality is important so transaction are also important. Is there any alternative way to check content and save the performance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

web_reg_find() does some logic based on the response sent from the server and therefore takes time. LoadRunner is aware that this is not actual time that will be perceived by the real user and therefore reports it as "wasted time" for the transaction. If you check the log for this transaction you will see something like this:

Notify: Transaction "login" ended with "Pass" status (Duration: 4.6360 **Wasted Time: 0.0062**).

The time the transaction took and out of that time how much time was wasted on LoadRunner internal operations.

Note that when you will open the result in Analysis the transaction times will be reported without the wasted time (i.e. Analysis will report the time as it is perceived by the real user).

Answer (score 1):

The amount of time taken for the processing of web_reg_find() also seems unusually long.   As web_reg_find() is both memory and CPU bound (holding the page in ram and running string comparisons) I would look at other possibilities as to why it takes an additional two seconds.  My hypothesis is that you have a resource constricted, or over subscribed load generator.   Look at the performance of a control group for this type of user, 1 user loaded by itself on a load generator.   Compare your control group to the behavior of the global group.  If you see a deviation then this is due to a local resource constriction which is showing as slowed virtual users.   This would have an impact on your measurement of response time as well.

I deliberately underload my load generators to avoid any possibility of load generator coloration plus employing a control generator in the group to measure any possible coloration.

Answer (score 0):

the time which is taken by web_reg_find is calculated as waste time...